# How to add variable in multiline string in Karate?

Tags: karate

Trying to use variable in multiline string but without success. May you please give me some hint how to do that? Thank you.

```
    * def LocalDateTime = Java.type('java.time.LocalDateTime')
    * def createDate = LocalDateTime.now()
    And request
    """
    {
      "id": 444444,
      "date": "#createdDate",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#embedded-expressions

It should be:

```
And request
"""
{
  "id": 444444,
  "date": "#(createdDate)"
}
"""
```

Comment: I had also typo in createDdate. Thanks.